# Where should I put my Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a reset password functionality on my project. I am sending a link to the user with a token. After they click on the link I need to go inside my `HomeController` and fire up the `ResetPassword` method. My problem is that I am not sure where I have to put the `ResetPassword` Partial View (that is modal), wherever I put it, it brings in when I open the login page.

consider this link in user email:

`http://...myurlaction=resetpassword&userid=5&email=test@yahoo.com&token=1234564`

when they click on it I need to go to this method:

first got to get method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("resetpassword")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ResetPassword(ResetPasswordRequest resetPasswordRequest)
{
    //check if Token is valid show the view
    return PartialView();
}
```

after post, go to `POST` method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("resetpassword")]
public ActionResult ResetPassword(ResetPasswordView resetPasswordView)
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

and this is partial view:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">x</span>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("resetpassword", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <h5>Reset Your Loan Center Password</h5>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Email Address</td><td><input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="jdoe@example.com"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="Password" name="Password" placeholder="Create Password"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Confirm Password</td><td><input type="Password" name="ConfirmPassword" placeholder="Re-enter Password"></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Reset Password"></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="errMessage" colspan="2">
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
</div>
```

My problem is that I don't know where I have to have `@Html.Partial("Login")`
because anywhere I have it show reset password view even if I don't need to show it.

Comment: You POST method also requires `[AllowAnonymous]` - the user has not been authorized yet (and they should not have the same signature)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, the thing is that is goes to post after I enter values in view but it is not goes to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your description, I guess that you use `PartialView` because you want to reuse the code of the `Login` page. Basically, your `Login` page has 2 states: one for login and another one for resetting password. To know which state is activated, you should have a flag in your `Login` page, something like:

```
@if (Viewbag["state"] == "Login") {
    Html.RenderPartial("Login");
} else {
    Html.RenderPartial("resetpassword");
}
```

Then, what you have to do is set the appropriate  value of the `Viewbag` on your `LoginController` and `ResetPasswordController`, like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("resetpassword")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ResetPassword(ResetPasswordRequest resetPasswordRequest)
{
    //check if Token is valid show the view
    Viewbag["state"] = "ResetPassword";
    return YourLoginPage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the partial view should be in the Views\Home folder of the application as you are calling the partial from your Home Controller. As a suggestion, maybe you can move your action method to an Account controller as strictly speaking reseting a password is more of an "Account" functionality rather than something that resides in your home controller. In this case your partial view will then be added to Views\Account.

Comment: I mean where I have to put the    @Html.Partial("resetpassword")